# For loop setting variable to condition

Tags: c++, variables, for-loop

The counter variable in my for loop gets set to the value of the condition upon first entering the loop. I have never heard of this happening, I wrote a very similar version of this code a month ago or so on this same system, and did not have this problem.

This is being compiled and built by Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 Visual C++ on a 64-bit Windows Vista computer. I have commented out all of my unnecessary code and it still caused this error. The code, with all comments removed is below:

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 

cout<<"Simple Watch Region Test\n";
cout<<"-----------------------\n";

//get number of tracks
cout<<"  Enter Number of Tracks to Run: ";
unsigned int totalNumberOfTracksToRun;
cin>>totalNumberOfTracksToRun;

unsigned short currentTrack = 0;
cout<<"currentTrack starts at "<<currentTrack<<endl;

for( currentTrack; currentTrack < totalNumberOfTracksToRun; currentTrack++);
{

    cout<<"current is "<<currentTrack<<endl;

     }

    return 0;
```

}

stdafx.h:

```
#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__9455C912_1697_486F_A680_AAE1D0B22611__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H__9455C912_1697_486F_A680_AAE1D0B22611__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
```

And the output is:

```
Simple Watch Region Test
-----------------------
  Enter Number of Tracks to run: 5
currentTrack starts at 0
current is 5
Press Any Key to continue
```

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

You have a semicolon at the end of your for statement:

```
for( currentTrack; currentTrack < totalNumberOfTracksToRun; currentTrack++);
                                                     // get rid of this ---^
```

It means the for loop runs, doing nothing, until `currentTrack` becomes equal to `totalNumberOfTracksToRun` and only then is the following block executed. This is why it appears that `currentTrack` has instantly jumped to 5.

Answer (score 4):

You have a stray `;`:

```
for( currentTrack; currentTrack < totalNumberOfTracksToRun; currentTrack++);
//                                                                         |
//                                                                       here
```

which means the `for` only increases `currentTrack` until it reaches `totalNumberOfTracksToRun` before going to the next lines.